# What to do with the OAuth2 url provided by Google

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I have created a nice OAuth2 service in my application such that my web client makes a request like so:

```
URI: /user/link?service=YT
Method: GET
```

And the service responds like so:

```
{
   status: "SERVICE_NOT_LINKED",
   auth_url: "http://somelonggoogleaddress..../"
}
```

The idea here is I would load that auth_url into a Bootstrap modal dialog, let the user authorize my app, and when the Google OAuth servers redirect and callback into my system, I would display a friendly message in the modal which tells them they successfully authorized with YouTube (or whatever) and they can close the modal.

The problem I'm facing is I can't seem to get this to work with [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) by simply setting it's "remote" property to the url from Google.  What happens is I get an error stating I can't show content from another site (essentially).

How do I overcome this problem?  Do I have to proxy the request through my own service?  That is, make a server-side service in my application which loads the URL from google and returns the content to use in the popover?

P.S. I don't want to do a full-page redirect, I don't feel that's the best UX choice for our app.

Comment: In my experience, you may have to compromise on your UX ideals. The primary goal of Oauth is security, and it really likes to have the browser window and URL to itself so the user can be assured that all is well. I suspect your final suggestion "... proxy through my own service" is the right one.

Comment: I would not recommend attempting to proxy OAuth login and consent pages through your own service.  In addition to security concerns (a major goal of OAuth is to avoid applications ever needing to handle passwords, which you would be proxying in this case) - I doubt it will improve the user experience. Users will now need to login a second time in addition to giving consent (normally the user is likely already logged in to a session with Google - by proxying the service that will require another session).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that's working as intended - see similar [OAuth not working inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073883/oauth-not-working-inside-an-iframe). Google users should not be typing their password into any page that they can't easily verify comes from Google (for example by examining the URL bar).

Comment: afaik, Bootsrap remote is not using an iframe. I suspect the error message the OP is getting is to do with CORS.

Comment: My comment wasn't so much in regards to the mechanism used - the working as intended is not allow obscuring of the URL of the login page - Google users should never enter their password on any page they can't verify is legitimately served by Google.

Comment: This is right. I think _it is_ the best UX choice to just open the login page in a new (popup) window. No sane user would enter their password on the wrong domain anyway. Google could rightfully flag your app as malicious if you tried to get users enter their credentials in your service.