# How to authenticate iframe against AAD (oauth)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, iframe, sharepoint, oauth-2.0

A (SharePoint Online) page has an iframe to a .NET MVC application. The MVC application lives in a separate domain. Both SharePoint Online and MVC app use AAD and allow access for the same users (AAD tenant)

Now when a user opens the SharePoint page (in Windows 7) the iframe fails to redirect user to the AAD login page (because this is disallowed - see [OAuth not working inside an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9073883/oauth-not-working-inside-an-iframe) or https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-v2-23#section-10.13)

After unsuccessful googling I decided to play around with this a bit and came up with something that works but is ugly:

1. User signs in to SharePoint. The iframe on page is hidden
2. JavaScript (jquery) on page makes a jsonp call to the MVC app

If the call succeeds we show the iframe and are happy

3. If the call fails we redirect user to an MVC page (full redirect). We carry the current url in querystring
4. User authenticates against AAD
5. MVC page redirects user back to our SharePoint Online page

Now iframe successfully shows content and we are happy, except that the above solution has a lot of code to maintain:

- JavaScript redirect logic
- jsonp request (error handling not so straightforward. Actually this is timeout based)
- extra MVC action to redirect user back
- unoptimal ux (some waiting and redirects. Back button would cause trouble)

What would be a better solution or how these things are typically solved?

(another question would be why my home PC seems to show iframe content after only signing in once to SharePoint online)

Comment: did you found a better approach?

Comment: Nope. We first started to build kind of a SharePoint app adapter for the MVC app but eventually (in our specific use case) decided to leave the app separate from SharePoint - users go there via links in SharePoint pages and get back to where they came from via a dynamic link on the MVC page. (our use case might also be a bit different because we needed the standalone MVC version in any case and this way avoided all the extra SP app boilerplate and deployment hassle. But I think this is quite specific and typically in SharePoint development building an app from the start might be better option)